# "Package 'open-vm-tools' has no installation candidate" on Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, apt, vmware, debian-installer

I'm following these instructions to install VMWare open tools:

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tools/11.0.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vmwaretools.doc/GUID-C48E1F14-240D-4DD1-8D4C-25B6EBE4BB0F.html

In particular:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

However, after the second command I get:

[image]

How is this resolved?

As per received comment:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any chance you can copy and paste the information, instead of posting screenshots?

Comment: @StephenKitt Unfortunately not. I'm on a Mac, with Debian in a VM and copy-paste isn't working, or i would :)

Comment: Thanks, follow the advice in the linked question and you should be able to install the package.

Comment: @mezamorphic Pointing out that all you have to do is SSH to the VM from Terminal.